# Why is the internal energy of an entropic spring 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In a lecture for a class I'm in right now, we talked about a polymer as an entropic spring. Here's the set-up:

Imagine a polymer in one dimension with a total length $N$ (ie. $N$ connected monomers). Suppose $n_R$ subunits (ie. monomers) are oriented to the right, and $n_L$ subunits are oriented to the left. Find the Helmholtz free energy.

We used the definition $F = U - TS$ for the free energy, and we said that since $U$ in this case is 0, $F = -TS = -k_B T \ln(\Omega)$.

My question is: why can we say that $U$ must be 0? I may have missed writing something down in the lecture, but don't see what about this situation would imply zero internal energy.

Comment: What type of energy is your internal energy?

Comment: @AaronStevens we've defined it using the first law, so (by this point in the class) as either $U=Q+W$, or $dU = TdS - PdV$

Comment: Is it possible that the professor has assumed that $n_L=n_R$?

Comment: They have just assumed that $U=0$, in this particular model. It’s like how you assume $P = nRT/V$ for an ideal gas. Why does pressure always have to equal that? It doesn’t always, but for an ideal gas it holds by definition.

Comment: @Macrophage The professor gave examples of such a polymer and none of the examples had $n_L = n_R$, so I don't think so.

Comment: @knzhou Okay, that makes sense. I must have missed when he said that was an assumption he was making. Thanks!

Comment: @knzhou So by definition $U=0$ in this case?

Comment: @AaronStevens that’s strange, I think somehow the energy depends on how many units you have in different orientations

Comment: I did some more searching, this looks like it could be a model of an ideal chain, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_chain#Entropic_elasticity_of_an_ideal_chain), the internal energy of an ideal chain is constant if the two free ends are attached to some sort of micro-manipulation device, which feels relevant, but the problem definition is still missing some things to make that the case here, and I'm not sure where that's coming from.

Comment: @Macrophage It depends on the model. $U = 0$ for some simple models of polymers, but not all. It's like how $\partial U / \partial V |_T = 0$ for some simple models of gases. The professor is just starting with something simple.

Comment: @rarelyNecessary This particular simple model is just assuming that there's no change in the energy when you rotate a bond. Then the energy is a constant, so since it never changes you might as well subtract off a constant to set it to zero.

Comment: @knzhou Yeah that is what I was thinking, and that is what makes more sense

Comment: @rarelyNecessary is it internal energy that is taken to be zero or is it the change in internal energy?